# How to disable warnings about parse source map

Tags: reactjs, expo

I have been working on a project in React Native using Expo. I was using Victory-native and to be able to use it on a web browser I started using webpack-config. This allowed me to run it on a browser but it also started giving me a lot of warnings. My site builds without problems but I would like to disable/get rid of the warnings. I have tried multiple things like a .env file, craco, GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false, updating parse5, using craco alias. I dont know how to fix it. Is this fixable or should I just look for another way or just live with the warnings?
WARNING in ./node_modules/parse5/dist/cjs/tree-adapters/default.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/@expo/webpack-config/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from '.\node_modules\parse5\dist\cjs\tree-adapters\default.js.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '.\node_modules\parse5\dist\cjs\tree-adapters\default.js.map'

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

using cross-env package worked for me.

here's the blog post about it. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/failed-to-parse-source-map-in-create-react-app

```
...
"scripts": {
  "start": "expo start",
  "android": "expo start --android",
  "ios": "expo start --ios",
  "web": "cross-env GENERATE_SOURCEMAP=false expo start --web"
},
```